# symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff not working

Tags: symfony1, migration, doctrine

I've tried on two separate development machines, but I can't get the doctrine:generate-migrations-diff to work.

I keep getting the same error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ToPrfxPage' not found in /private/var/folders/a1/a1HQHKvmG-4VtnVS-e4i1E+++TI/-Tmp-/toprfx_doctrine_tmp_dirs/ToPrfxLibraryPage.php on line 32
```

It looks like it's generating a temporary class that it's not able to load again. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a doctrine:clean-model-files

It sounds like you still have some old model classes that are trying to be loaded, but are not there anymore.  This command will clean your solution with anything models that are no longer matching up with your schema.yml file.